# Unable to fine related module of `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` class

Tags: java, module, java-9

I am applying java 9 modules to my java application. In my java
application it contains `import` statement `import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`.

When I add `module-info.java` file, that statement provides compilation error as expected. Because I need to add `requires <module name>` statement to `module-info.java` file.

But I am unable to find what is the related module for that import statement. Can anyone help to find the `requires` statement related to `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` this imported class.

I explored furthermore and found the solution is to add automatic module name to the module-info.java file based on relevant jar file name. In this case my relevant jar file name is `jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final`.

According to the conventions I tried to get automatic module name from jar file name. I tried following instances but not worked.

`jboss.jaxrs.api_2.spec`
`jboss.jaxrs.api`

Can anyone help me to fine the correct automatic module name? Or is there any other way to solve this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.